# JQuery Timeline breaks all other javascript on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implement JS [Timeline](http://timeline.verite.co/) but when I paste the code into my site the timeline works fine but disrupts all my other JQuery scripts.

The timeline code I add is:

```
<div id="timeline-embed"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

   var timeline_config = {
   width:  "100%",
   height: "100%",
   //source: eventdata,
   source: 'js/timeline/test.json', 
   css:  'js/timeline/compiled/css/timeline.css', 
   js:  'js/timeline/compiled/js/timeline-min.js' 
  };

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/timeline/compiled/js/timeline-embed.js"></script>
```

If I remove it every thing runs fine again.

Has anyone had any issues like this before?

EDIT: my site with the code if anyone's interested: http://www.clavecontraclave.com

Comment: You should first load the plugin and then execute the related scripts.

Comment: He's not executing anything. He's defining a config var.

Comment: jquery files are conflicting each other... can you let us know what the other thing you are doing with jquery??? So that we can answer you more effectively

Comment: @raman I have a slideshow plugin, a fancybox plugin and a couple of little animations happening

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'

Comment: Took a look at your page, you have two jQuery libraries being loaded. 1.8 Loads first, then 1.5.1. You need to remove 1.5.2, you'll see the errors go away. Try it. **Edit** Also, you have two jQuery UI Libraries loading, get rid of version 1.7.

Comment: It's 1.5.1 - and you also have like 12 DOM ready wrappers, you should consolidate those.

Comment: DOM ready wrappers make no difference, consolidation isn't even an issue. Many sites perform header injections and it's required to split the ready functionality across multiple scripts.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks! That was the issue! you should make that an answer so I can up vote it

Comment: Thanks captain obvious. My point was that his code is all over the place - the clean-up effort would reveal the bugs.

Comment: @AlienWebGuy Calm down. No one's here to persecute or point out shortcomings. Have a nice day.